# iOS: addObserver and superview query

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I have a uiview named subview1. I add this as subview to a couple of other views depending on certain situations. Now I have the following code

```
[subView1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"superview" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

My problem is the obserValueForKeypath function is never called

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if (self.subView1 == (UIView*)object) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"superview"]) {
            NSLog(@"superview changed %@",change);

        }
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong here.

Comment: can you show both .h an .m file..?

Comment: According to apple:
"The class must emit KVO change notifications for the property." I'm not sure that UIView emits KVO change notifications for `superview` (i.e calls `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`).

Answer (score -1):

Just check that if it is going into first if block , the problem might be there.Also check if you have declared property for variable for which you are setting the observer if it is in different class.

Comment: Nope it dosent even enter the block and yes have checked the second part too. observerValueForKeyPath is just not being called